# Difference between normalization and normalisation

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

Regard this [review](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7474565/revisions). I used normalization instead of normalisation.

Google says "Normalisation is the process of taking data from a problem and reducing it to a set of relations while ensuring data integrity and eliminating data redundancy. Data integrity - all of the data in the database are consistent, and satisfy all integrity constraints."

And "Database normalization, or simply normalization, is the process of organizing the columns (attributes) and tables (relations) of a relational database to minimize data redundancy."

> Can you explain it in formal way, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normalization and normalisation are the same word, spelled in the American English respectively British English way (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#-ise.2C_-ize_.28-isation.2C_-ization.29)). There is absolutely no difference in meaning between them.

On Stack Exchange, neither American nor British spelling is preferred. As an editor, you should not override the author's decision which one to use. That's why your edit was rolled back - see for example [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252504/4751173) on Meta Stack Overflow.